# Recurrency not working well in Web Crawler project

Tags: java, algorithm, web

For excerise I want to make my own Web Crawler but I have a problem with recurrent invocation of my crawl method. It should start for every link in my links array and goes so on until I decide to abort whole program but it only goes for first element in that array so it simply goes back and forth without any progress. How can I fix this?

Crawler.java

```
package regularmikey.mikecrawler;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Crawler implements Runnable {

    private Elements links;
    private Document doc;
    private String start_url;


    public Crawler(){};
    public Crawler(String url){start_url = url;};


    public void crawl(String url)  {

        try {
            System.out.println(url);
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title);

            links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                if(AdressValidator.validAddress(link.attr("href"))) {
                crawl(link.attr("href"));
                }
            }
        } catch (org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void run() {

            crawl(start_url);

    }
}
```

App.java

```
package regularmikey.mikecrawler;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Crawler("http://facebook.com"));
       thread.run();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a List of url that you have already reached.

```
private List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

//some code

for (Element link : links) {
            if(!urls.contains(link.attr("abs:href"))){
                urls.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                crawl(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
}
```

EDIT : completed with @PallyP Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your

`crawl(link.attr("href"))`

To

`crawl(link.attr("abs:href"))`

Adding the `abs:` prefix will return the absolute URL (e.g. "http://facebook.com")

Answer (score 0):

The private members of `class Crawler` are overwritten by each (recursive) call to `crawl()`:

```
private Elements links;
private Document doc;

public void crawl(String url)  {

    try {
        // ...
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        links = doc.select("a[href]");

            crawl(link.attr("href"));
    }
}
```

This means, if a recursive call to `crawl()` returns, `links` and `doc` are not restored to their previous values.

This should be fixed first by using local variables for `links` and `doc` inside `crawl()`.